# I am trying to use bigquery_operator operator from apache airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to use bigquery_operator operator from apache with airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator but I can not find an appropriate module.

My airflow version is 2.6.1

I am trying to replicate same result from the udemy course:
https://www.udemy.com/course/apache-airflow-course/
Using windows 11 and linux as subsystem.

I read some questions here but all of them are using airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator and don't have a problem, so I don't know why it is not showing up on my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out airflow.contrib is a legacy, new way of importing bigquery can be found here:

https://apache.googlesource.com/airflow/+/fbf874a0f7a6313321af43600e0ba564de6899db/UPDATING.md#airflow-200b1

For my case, instead of `airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator`
I should have used
`airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery.BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator`

I have some more problems now regarding the connection, but I think now I am on the right track.

P.S It wouldn't hurt to update the udemy course too.

Comment: `BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator` is depreciated you should use `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably viewing an outdated course.
The Airflow documentation is the best source to stay up to date.
Specifically for your question the operator code is not part of Airflow release it's part of [apache-airflow-providers-google](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/index.html) package.

You should use [BigQueryInsertJobOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery.BigQueryInsertJobOperator)

Code example can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html#execute-bigquery-jobs).

Comment: Thanks for the comment and yes it was because of outdated source code, BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator worked out fine for me, maybe BigQueryInsertJobOperator would be same but the problem was clear.